# How to order the Shield UI Animation properties for different series?

Tags: shieldui

I have a chart with two types of graphs: line and bar. And I want to set two different loading times for them as the code shows:

```c
seriesSettings: {
line: {
    applyAnimation: {
        duration: 7500           
    }
}
bar: {
    applyAnimation: {
        duration: 3500
    }
}    
},
```

However the chart won’t show. When I remove the settings the chart works fine again. Is there a special sequence I need to set these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special sequence. Regardless of the series types used, you can set their delays in just any order. In your code there is a typing error. Find correct one below:

```
seriesSettings: {
line: {
    applyAnimation: {
        duration: 7500           
    }
},
bar: {
    applyAnimation: {
        duration: 3500
    }
}    
},
```